# TypeError: descriptor 'attribute' for 'Class' objects doesn't apply to a 'Class' object

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

Given a TimeKey class:

```
from collections import abc
import datetime as dt
from typing import Generator, Union
from dataclasses import dataclass

# impl details ommitted for simplicity
def _parsetime(start): return start

def _strfkey(key): return key

def _strflabel(label): return label

def _strftime(val): return val

@dataclass(init=False)
class TimeKey(abc.Mapping):
    @classmethod
    def fromdict(cls, d: dict):
        return cls(
            key=d["time_key"],
            label=d["time_key_label"],
            unit=d["time_key_unit"],
            start=d["time_key_start"],
            end=d["time_key_end"],
        )

    __slots__ = ["key", "label", "unit", "start", "end"]

    key: str
    label: str
    unit: str
    start: Union[int, float, str, dt.date, dt.datetime, dt.time]
    end: Union[int, float, str, dt.date, dt.datetime, dt.time]

    def __init__(
        self,
        unit,
        start,
        end,
        key=None,
        **kwargs,
    ):
        if unit not in (None, "year", "month", "week", "week_of_month", "day"):
            raise ValueError(f"Unsupported unit value: '{unit}'")

        self.unit = unit
        self.start = _parsetime(start)
        self.end = _parsetime(end)
        self.key = key or _strfkey(self.unit, self.start, self.end, **kwargs)
        self.label = _strflabel(self.unit, self.start, self.end, **kwargs)

    def keys(self):  # abc.Mapping protocol
        return self.PICKLED_KEYS

    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> str:
        key = "key" if key == "time_key" else key.replace("time_key_", "")
        val = getattr(self, key)
        return _strftime(self.unit, val) if key in ("start", "end") else val

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.PICKLED_KEYS)

    def __iter__(self) -> Generator[str, None, None]:
        yield from {
            ("time_key" if key == "key" else f"time_key_{key}"): val
            for key, val in self.__dict__.items()
        }

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            "time_key": self.key,
            "time_key_label": self.label,
            "time_key_unit": self.unit,
            "time_key_start": self.start,
            "time_key_end": self.end,
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state: dict):
        object.__setattr__(self, "unit", state["time_key_unit"])
        object.__setattr__(self, "start", state["time_key_start"])
        object.__setattr__(self, "end", state["time_key_end"])
        object.__setattr__(self, "key", state["time_key"])
        object.__setattr__(self, "label", state["time_key_label"])
```

When attempting to create an instance of the TimeKey through the **init** constructor:

```
TimeKey(key=self.key, unit=self.unit, start=self._start, end=self._end, **kwargs)
```

with

```
{'unit': 'month', 'start': datetime.date(2021, 11, 1), 'end': datetime.date(2021, 11, 30), 'key': '2021-11', 'kwargs': {}}
```

Then I get the following error:

```
--> 184         self.unit = unit
    185         self.start = _parsetime(start)
    186         self.end = _parsetime(end)

TypeError: descriptor 'unit' for 'TimeKey' objects doesn't apply to a 'TimeKey' object
```

This class has been stable (and has unit tests for a while), so I really don't understand why it breaks as such all of a sudden.
Any idea what may be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Well, code doesn't break all of a sudden. Have you e.g. changed your Python version?

Comment: I may have actually. The above was run in Jupyter Notebook, whereas normally this is run in python. The Jupyter kernel used is a direct reference to the poetry venv that I use everywhere else, and inspection of `sys.version` in Jupy returns the same as `python --version` while in shell - 3.8.7. But I'm willing to bet Jupyter Notebook may be a factor in this error.

Comment: I confirm this seems to be an environment issue - using the REPL within the poetry venv does not reproduce the issue

Comment: Restarting Jupyter Lab fixes the issue ლ(¯ロ¯"ლ)

Comment: In that case, one plausible idea is that you're inadvertently executing/reloading the code with TimeKey multiple times, so there are several identical classes called TimeKey, but with different ids... or something.

Comment: That sounds like it's what's happening - I import the TimeKey class through an import that is `autoreloaded` using the `autoreload` magic.

Comment: TFW I come back here by searching the error... for the same class - a wild mix of amused & bemused.
EDIT: And restarting Jupyter Lab fixed the issue... again :D